# Alternation of positive and negative values

Tags: sql, sql-server

thank you for attention.
I have a table called "PROD_COST" with 5 fields

```
(ID,Duration,Cost,COST_NEXT,COST_CHANGE).
```

I need extra field called "groups" for aggregation.

- Duration = number of days the price is valid (1 day=1row).
- Cost = product price in  this day.
- Cost_next = lead(cost,1,0).
- Cost_change = Cost_next - Cost.

Now i need to group by Cost_change. It can be 
positive,negative or 0 values.

```
+----+---+------+------+------+
|  1 | 1 | 10   | 8,5  | -1,5 |
|  2 | 1 | 8,5  | 12,2 | 3,7  |
|  3 | 1 | 12,2 | 5,3  | -6,9 |
|  4 | 1 | 5,3  | 4,2  | 1,2  |
|  5 | 1 | 4,2  | 6,2  | 2    |
|  6 | 1 | 6,2  | 9,2  | 3    |
|  7 | 1 | 9,2  | 7,5  | -2,7 |
|  8 | 1 | 7,5  | 6,2  | -1,3 |
|  9 | 1 | 6,2  | 6,3  | 0,1  |
| 10 | 1 | 6,3  | 7,2  | 0,9  |
| 11 | 1 | 7,2  | 7,5  | 0,3  |
| 12 | 1 | 7,5  | 0    | 7,5  |
+----+---+------+------+------+`
```

I need to make a query, which will group it by first negative or positive value (+ - + - + -). Last one field is what i want. 
Sorry for my English `

```
+----+---+------+------+------+---+
|  1 | 1 | 10   | 8,5  | -1,5 | 1 |
|  2 | 1 | 8,5  | 12,2 | 3,7  | 2 |
|  3 | 1 | 12,2 | 5,3  | -6,9 | 3 |
|  4 | 1 | 5,3  | 4,2  | 1,2  | 4 |
|  5 | 1 | 4,2  | 6,2  | 2    | 4 |
|  6 | 1 | 6,2  | 9,2  | 3    | 4 |
|  7 | 1 | 9,2  | 7,5  | -2,7 | 5 |
|  8 | 1 | 7,5  | 6,2  | -1,3 | 5 |
|  9 | 1 | 6,2  | 6,3  | 0,1  | 6 |
| 10 | 1 | 6,3  | 7,2  | 0,9  | 6 |
| 11 | 1 | 7,2  | 7,5  | 0,3  | 6 |
| 12 | 1 | 7,5  | 0    | 7,5  | 6 |
+----+---+------+------+------+---+`
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous because you do not specify what to do about "0" values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in SQL Server 2012 you can use the window functions to do this:

```
select 
  id, COST_CHANGE, sum(GRP) over (order by id asc) +1
from
(
  select
    *,
    case when sign(COST_CHANGE) != sign(isnull(lag(COST_CHANGE) 
      over (order by id asc),COST_CHANGE)) then 1 else 0 end as GRP
  from
    PROD_COST
) X
```

Lag will get the value from previous row, check the sign of it and compare it to the current row. If the values don't match, the case will return 1. The outer select will do a running total of these numbers, and every time there is 1, it will increase the total.

It is possible to use the same logic with older versions too, you'll just have to fetch the previous row from the table using the id and do running total by re-calculating all rows before the current one.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8b72/1)

Comment: that work's, that you very much! But my query must ignore 0 values....Gordon Linoff corrected it, but anyway there's some problem..

Answer (score 0):

James's answer is close but it doesn't handle the zero value correctly.  This is a pretty easy modification.  One tricky approximation uses differences between product changes:

```
select id, COST_CHANGE, sum(IsNewGroup) over (order by id asc) +1
from (select pc.*,
             (case when sign(cost_change) - sign(lag(cost_change) over (order by id)) between -1 and 1
                   then 0
                   else 1 -- `NULL` intentionally goes here
              end) IsNewGroup
      from Prod_Cost
     ) pc
```

For clarity, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3ca9/3) is a SQL Fiddle with zero values.  From my understanding of the question, the OP only wants an actual sign change.

This may still not be correct.  The OP simply is not clear about what to do about 0 values.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I really need to ignore 0 values, but can I have another problem with this code. For example, Cost changes: -8.24 ; 2.36 ; 0 ; -8.21 ; 8.21   Groups: 19; 20 ; 20; 20; 21.. But "groups" should be: 19 ; 20; 20; 21; 22.. I hope you understand